# Optional object with required fields in react-jsonschema-form

Tags: forms, reactjs, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Given a json schema like the one below, the react-jsonschema-form validator essentially requires both `shipping_address` and `billing_address` even though the `billing_address` is not listed as required. This is because the `address` type requires all three of its properties. How can I make the `billing_address` optional? It seems that react-jsonschema-form should simply no submit `billing_address` if not all of its `address` properties are filled in. Here is a [link](https://mozilla-services.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/#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) to the react-jsonschema-form playground.

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street_address": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "street_address",
        "city",
        "state"
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "billing_address": {
      "title": "Billing address",
      "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
    },
    "shipping_address": {
      "title": "Shipping address",
      "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "shipping_address"
  ]
}
```

Comment: that seems to be a problem with that validator, if you try with this http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ for example, not providing the billing address in the json data works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dynamic](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form#dynamic) schema dependencies to make the billing address conditionally displayed and required. This isn't the same as having an optional object but seem to suffice if you're willing to have a slightly different user experience. Here is a [link](https://mozilla-services.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/#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) to the react-jsonschema-form playground. It is best viewed, in my opinion, with live validation disabled (there's a checkbox in the upper-right of the page).

```js
{
  "definitions": {
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street_address": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "street_address",
        "city",
        "state"
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "different_addresses": {
      "title": "My billing address is different than my shipping address.",
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": false
    },
    "shipping_address": {
      "title": "Shipping address",
      "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "shipping_address"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "different_addresses": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "different_addresses": {
              "enum": [
                false
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "different_addresses": {
              "enum": [
                true
              ]
            },
            "billing_address": {
              "title": "Billing address",
              "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "billing_address"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using `dependencies` with `oneOf` was the key.

Answer (score 0):

my question is related to your JSON schema.

I need to target the "grandchild" of a parent object for a dependency.
Is this possible? In case of **"different_addresses"** being an object.

**For example**:

```
"dependencies": {
  "different_addresses": {
    "properties": {
      "OTHER_FIELD": {
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "properties": {
              "different_addresses": {
                "properties": {
                  "OTHER_FIELD": {
                    "enum": [
                      false
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```